# Performance impact on SELECT query after adding clustered indices

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sqlperformance

We have a **SELECT** operation that involves tables with around 20 millions of records. There are no Clustered Indices on the tables and there are Non-Clustered Indices stored in another Filegroup.

The system usually runs around 3 hours to complete. The system use **TABLE SCAN** for query and no non-clustered indices are involved.
So we tried to improve the duration by adding Clustered Indices back to the table. All indices and statistics are rebuilt.

However, now the system performs **Clustered Index Scan** instead of **Table Scan** and the result is much worse than before (3x slower).

So my questions are

1. Why clustered index scan is worse than table scan?
2. Is it a good idea to remove those Clustered Indices? INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE are not a concern at this moment.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: It's too general to give an answer. Please provide more details, including your queries and table/indicies structure.

Comment: Clustered indexes are usually a good idea *if* they organize your data in a sensible manner.  In other words, a good clustered index is usually good.  Trouble might be that you didn't pick a good clustered index.  Without seeing the query, the tables' schema, and the index definitions on the tables I suspect question #1 cannot be answered.  I'm fairly certain a complete answer would also require the execution plan for the query, as well.  Some sample data for the key fields would probably be useful, as well.